# How do I search on Bicycles at Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

How do I search for tags on Bicycles at Stack Exchange? If, for example I search for the tag [led-lights], I try gets a response like this:

The led-lights tag has no wiki summary, can you help us create it?

learn more…  top users  synonyms
  You are on the Unanswered tab.
  There are no unanswered questions at the moment.
  Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

Clicking the Questions tab or the Bicycles link at the top doesn't do anything.

I am using the Safari browser on Mac OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion).

(Maybe it is a Safari problem, searching seems to work in Chrome).

Perhaps someone with more reputation might like to move this to Meta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are on the `Unanswered` tab at the top right-ish. You probably want to click on `Newest` to see all questions with that tag in order of most recently modified.

Comment: You could be right. I think I got confused between Unanswered in the top row and unanswered in the second row of tabs. Now I have noticed both, Chrome and Safari work the same. Thanks.